# Have any prominent Christian Intelligent Design proponents discussed the issue of a potential infinite regress of intelligent designers?

Tags: creation, philosophy, intelligent-design, infinity

We can arrive at an [infinite regress](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/infinite-regress/) of designers as follows:

- Suppose that X is so complex that it's considered to show evidence of design. Accordingly, we infer that an intelligent designer must be behind X. Let ID<sub>1</sub> be this intelligent designer.
- We can ask the following question about ID<sub>1</sub>: **Is ID<sub>1</sub> at least as complex as X?** We have two possibilities:

  - if Complexity(ID<sub>1</sub>) >= Complexity(X), we can infer that there must be an intelligent designer ID<sub>2</sub> who designed ID<sub>1</sub>.
  - if Complexity(ID<sub>1</sub>) < Complexity(X), we are admitting that complexity can increase over time, which would sound great to the ears of evolutionists, so let's just ignore this case for the purposes of this analysis.
- So assuming the first case, we can infer that ID<sub>2</sub> must exist. But then we can ask the same question about ID<sub>2</sub>, and infer the existence of ID<sub>3</sub>, and then the existence of ID<sub>4</sub>, and the existence of ID<sub>5</sub>, and ...
- And thus we arrive at an infinite regress of intelligent designers.

Would ID proponents agree with this reasoning, and if so, do they find an infinite regress of intelligent designers problematic?

If one believes that infinite regresses of this kind are impossible, a possible solution would be to stop the regress by claiming that there has to be **a first undesigned designer** (just like the *unmoved mover* or *uncaused cause* of the cosmological arguments for God's existence), but I think this would essentially reduce ID to Creationism. Is there a way to solve the infinite regress problem without resorting to Creationism?

**I'm interested to know if any prominent Christian ID proponents have expressed any thoughts about this potential infinite regress problem**, while keeping a separation of concerns between Intelligent Design and Creationism. I'm suggesting this last requirement in light of articles such as this one: [Intelligent Design and Creationism Just Aren’t the Same](https://www.discovery.org/a/1329/)

---

For those interested in a broader range of answers to this very same question, you are welcome to have a look at a [cross-posted version](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99474/does-intelligent-design-id-entail-an-infinite-regress-of-designers-and-if-so) asked on Philosophy Stack Exchange. Judging by the reactions, I had much, much better luck over there.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146253/discussion-on-question-by-mark-have-any-prominent-christian-intelligent-design-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I'm not going to Answer because I don't think this is on topic (it's not asking about *Christianity*), but the short version is that ID doesn't try to answer that question. The point of ID is not to identify or explain the designer, but only to detect *when a designer has been active*. The question "whence the designer?" would be properly understood as an area for separate investigation.

Comment: This is more appropriately answered at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99474/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an area of focus in scholarly publications on Intelligent Design.

---

**Scoping Intelligent Design**

Intelligent Design is not a viewpoint restricted to Christians. It can include Jews, Muslims, and other faiths. Neither is Intelligent Design a viewpoint restricted to those who believe in God.

Though many proponents of Intelligent Design do believe in God, a person who is agnostic on the subject of God can still look at the evidence in cells, conclude through abductive reasoning that the best explanation of this evidence is that there is a designer, and remain uncertain as to the identity of the designer.

A Christian may believe the designer is God, a Muslim may believe the designer is Allah, and an agnostic may believe the designer is of an advanced extra-terrestrial race. DNA, developmental gene regulatory networks, epigenetic structures, and mechanical systems within cells provide reason to believe in an intelligent, powerful designer, but these alone do not provide the characterization of the designer--or the designer's intentions--that are a hallmark of religious texts. The common Christian view is that character & intentions are known because the Designer chose to reveal them.

Intelligent Design studies what the designer has revealed through the natural world<sup>1</sup>. Theology studies what the Designer has revealed through authorized representatives & texts.

--

**Infinite Regression**

Philosophically there is nothing inherently wrong with an infinite regression. Infinite regression/progression is common in theoretical models, and although we may struggle to wrap our minds around the concept of infinity (but to be fair, the quantum realm isn't exactly intuitive either), nothing in the evidence of design in cells validates or falsifies an infinite regression.

A commitment to materialism, or a specific set of theological views, may pose a problem for an infinite regression. But without the input of outside information, biology-based design arguments themselves are not going to exclude infinite regression *or* an unmoved mover.

--

**Conclusion**

Thus, the answers to the OP's questions, strictly from the discipline of Intelligent Design, would be:

*Have any prominent Christian Intelligent Design proponents discussed the issue of a potential infinite regress of intelligent designers?*

No, because this goes beyond what can be inferred from the data.

*Do [ID proponents] find an infinite regress of intelligent designers problematic?*

No. Proponents of Intelligent Design who wish to address this question would do so through the inputs of other disciplines, not through Intelligent Design. From the discipline of Intelligent Design neither the unmoved mover nor the infinite regression can be affirmed or denied.

*Is there a way to solve the infinite regress problem without resorting to Creationism?*

I see at least 2 possible ways to do so:

- Affirm the infinite regression
- Accept the reality of an unmoved mover without taking a position on specific theological claims about the unmoved mover.

---

**Appendix--entropy**

One of the agnostic approaches to this question is to assert that although life on earth must be designed, it may be that there are life forms elsewhere that developed along a different path and did not need to be designed. If those life forms advanced sufficiently to experiment with biology, such life forms could be the designers of life on earth.

We have to be careful with what is meant by "complexity"--which could be a post all its own--but because the universe tends towards entropy, it is unclear why we would expect the complex to come from the simple, rather than the other way around. I contend that there are no clear examples of an entity designing something more complex than itself.

E.g. beaver cells are more complex than beaver dams, spider cells are more complex than spider webs, human cells (& minds!) are more complex than any machine humans have (yet) produced. The world of AI is...complicated. It may yet disprove my suggestion, but no software of the present is as complex as a human.

In the realm of design, then, "Complexity(ID1) >= Complexity(X)" is true for every design available for evaluation. "Complexity(ID1) < Complexity(X)" appears to be devoid of empirical support.

---

<sup>1 - specifically biology. Teleological arguments from the fine-tuning of the universe create a much greater problem for extra-terrestrial design theories, but cosmology is outside the scope of this post</sup>

Comment: Hey Hold. I forgot to thank you for the answer. It's striking how the same question can cause so disimilar reactions between this site and the philosophy site. You can find the Philosophy SE mirror of the question here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99474/

Comment: @Mark sure thing, it seemed a shame for an insightful question to receive no answer. Wow - that is quite a divergent result between sites.

Comment: A most thoughtful answer. Re. A.I., it may yet turn out that it is a machine humans have begotten in their own likeness. Already humans are having unhealthy 'conversations' with today's chat bots, so impressed by their supposed knowledge, they take everything they say as gospel truth. Attempts to 'instill' ethics into them will always crack in the face of financial profits. Sinful humans can only beget more sinfulness, be that in procreated children, or manufactured A.I. machines. Your suggestion is not threatened by future A.I.

Comment: "Philosophically there is nothing inherently wrong with an infinite regression" some elaboration on this point would be helpful.